# how to build a two colour navbar in html, css?

Tags: html, css

How to you create the following design idea (see image) using html / CSS into a navbar? I will add the rest of the links afterwards.

[image: Navbar style I am trying to create]

Comment: SVG, Pseudo-Elements, Linear-gradient -> take your pick... Also it is expected that you have done research efford and tried to solve an issue on your own. There are literally thousands of simliar topics here and on the web about diagonal shaped elements.

Comment: You can use SVG background in your nav bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` with defined stops

```css
.header {
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, skyblue 50%, royalblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
```